# Dialog menu not receiving Enter key

Tags: menu, mfc, keyboard-events, enter, dialogbasedapp

I’m currently writing an MFC dialog app which has a menu. The menu displays correctly and the menu entries work correctly via mouse, accelerators, and hotkeys (e.g., to quit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>,<kbd>Q</kbd>).

Unfortunately, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key doesn’t seem to work. That is, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will open the *File* menu and pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> will highlight the *Quit* entry, but pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will not select it.

I know that using menus in dialog apps can be a bit tricky, but I’ve done this successfully before. However, that was a long time ago with a customized VS wizard, so I am trying to remember how to do this from scratch. I tried checking my old code, but could not find anything in reference to `VK_RETURN`. (No, there’s nothing special in `PreTranslateMessage`.)

[These two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214584/keyboard-enter-key-not-working-in-mfc-dialog-box) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699148/why-doesnt-onkeydown-catch-key-events-in-a-dialog-based-mfc-project) are related, but they want the dialog to receive the key, I need the menu to get it.

Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using Spy++ to see who may be handling the Enter key?  Try spying the dialog.

Comment: Actually, Spy++ doesn’t seem to work at all. I even tried running it as admin and setting it to watch the Windows Calculator, but it still logs nothing whatsoever.

Comment: I made a simple MFC dialog based application with a menu using the VS wizard, hitting `Enter` after highlighting a menu item seems to work ok (even when there's a multiline Edit control with WantReturn that has the focus) -- there must be some code in your application that swallows the enter key...

Comment: Are you using the correct (eg. 32 vs 64 bit) version of Spy++?